# How to bundle a downloaded lib

Tags: webpack, dhtmlx

I've downloaded a javascript + css + images library ([dxhtml](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__index.html)) and want to bundle it instead of hardcoding the script/css imports in the html. But the javascript is not a module (it doesn't do `module.exports`).

What is the best way to achieve this? Should I add the main file in the library to `entry` in `webpack.config.js`?

I'm successfully bundling all kinds of node modules, but I've tried to include local files with no success.

Comment: Hopefully someone can chime in and give us a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by configuring webpack with a css-loader and an exports-loader.

**CSS Loader**

Follow webpack's official CSS loader steps:
https://github.com/webpack/css-loader

**JavaScript Exports Loader**

In order to load the JavaScript, use exports-loader to specify which functions you want to export from the DHTMLX file.  First, install exports-loader:

```
npm install --save-dev exports-loader
```

Next, specify the functions that you want exported from dhtmlx:

```
require('./dhtmlx/tree/codebase/dhtmlxtree.css');

var dhx = require('exports?' +
    'treeObject=dhtmlXTreeObject' +
    '!./dhtmlx/tree/codebase/dhtmlxtree.js');

var myTree = new dhx.treeObject('treeboxbox_tree', '100%', '100%', 0);
```